# Get the Hex String of a byte array

Tags: string, vb6, binary

In VB6, is there a way to obtain the string representation of a byte array? I need the equivalent of `sys.fn_varbintohexstr` in SQL server. I'm sorry if it's a silly question, but my VB6 is... not very good... Help?

Comment: Umm, `fn_varbintohexstr` returns the Hexadecimal represenation of a Varbinary string.  That is something entirely different from "Getting a string from a byte array".  The first reformats binary into hex, the second reformats binary into Ascii/Unicode.  Which do you want?

Comment: Binary into hex, and stuff that into a string.

Comment: Well, binary into hex then. Sorry for the misused terms...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a function that I found at [another site](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?559398-Byte-array-to-hex-string):

```
Function ByteArrayToHexStr(b() As Byte) As String
   Dim n As Long, i As Long

   ByteArrayToHexStr = Space$(3 * (UBound(b) - LBound(b)) + 2)
   n = 1
   For i = LBound(b) To UBound(b)
      Mid$(ByteArrayToHexStr, n, 2) = Right$("00" & Hex$(b(i)), 2)
      n = n + 3
   Next
End Function
```

Comment: That seems to work... I removed the spaces between each pair of bytes though... I don't need them in the output string. Thanks! Incidentally, do you know how can I change the title of the question? I do think it is misleading...